# Custom grid resize in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, resize, grid

I am using [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/making-timeline-control-for-datagrid-in-wpf/) `DataGrid` (which is nothing more than a `DataGrid` with more stuff). I would like to be able to resize vertically the size of the grid, not the size of its rows or columns. In the image I attached you can a see a huge blank space between the first row and the bottom of the window. What I need is that when the mouse hovers by the top of the grid (somewhere in the top corner of the grid's header) to have a resize cursor. When resizing, the size of the elements in the grid don't need to change, just the total height of the grid.

Also, the maximum height the grid should always be is just bellow the "Add event" buttom.

In other words, I want the user to be able to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: I think your terminology is all mixed up, either that or my head is.  I really don't understand the question to be honest.  It doesn't make much sense from a user point of view either.  Have you investigated using VerticalAlignment="Stretch" properties, or using a GridSplitter?

Comment: @Jammer hopefully my last edit helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try with this is to use a `GridSplitter`.  I'm presuming you have a `Grid` layout that is something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" /> // This is where the button lives
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
</Grid>
```

If you add a `GridSplitter` to row one you'll get the desired effect:

```
<GridSplitter 
        ResizeDirection=”Rows”
        Grid.Row=”1″ 
        Width=”Auto”
        Height=”3″
        HorizontalAlignment=”Stretch”
        VerticalAlignment=”Stretch”
        Margin=”0″/>
```

Comment: The grid is entirely constructed in the code, not in the `XAML`. Can you provide a code version of your `XAML`?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you are constructing this in code and not using XAML?